# C# Blazor Webassembly custom authorize attribute not working debug

Tags: debugging, attributes, blazor, webassembly

I found a problem with the authorization attributes in the blazor. I wrote a class for working with roles in attributes in order to pass them through parameters.

First variant - Default attribute

```
@attribute [Authorize]
```

Second variant - Custom attribute

```
@attribute [AuthorizeRoles(RoleType.Administrator)]

public class AuthorizeRolesAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeRolesAttribute(params RoleType[] roles)
    {
        Roles = RoleTypeExtension.GetStringRoles(roles);
    }
}
```

When I use first variant then all working, but then I use second variant I have problem with Debug from all project and project work very well. I have error "The breakpoint cannot be hit. Unbound breakpoint"

How to solve this problem?

You can use this example - https://vivien-chevallier.com/Articles/create-a-custom-authorizeattribute-that-accepts-parameters-of-type-enum

Comment: The linked article example is in french, will not be easy for people to help you here. But let's see if somebody can still help you or use a google translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it should be an error in the Blazor. For more relevant information please see [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/53238) on GitHub

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29992501)

Comment: It problem was "When mono.cecil is loading the assembly and this assembly references to another assembly, it searchs for this assembly on a cache and on folders, in our case, we were not adding the assemblies loaded in this cache, so mono.cecil was failing and it was not possible to set breakpoint in any assembly that references another assembly."